# Python: Concatenate 2 irregular sized images by automatically detecting the sizes

Tags: image, python-2.7, opencv, merge

**Problem Statement:** I have 2 images of different sizes. *First image (1320 x 950)* and *second image (1260 x 744)*. I am interested in concatenating these images next to each other so that they fit on my screen monitor (screen resolution: *1920 x 1080*). Tried using np.concatenate but the problem is that the images need to be of same sizes. I tried the following but I was not able to solve this issue. How could I solve the problem?

**What I tried:**

```
for i in range(File_start,File_stop,1):
    img1 = cv2.imread('Z:/04_RD/PP/img'+'_'+str(i)+'.jpg')
    img2 = cv2.imread('Z:/04_RD/GRF/GRF'+'_'+str(i)+'.jpg')

    h1, w1 = img1.shape[:2]
    h2, w2 = img2.shape[:2]

    visl = np.zeros((max(h1, h2), w1+w2,3), np.uint8)

    visl[:h1, :w1,:3] = img1
    visl[:h2, w1:w1+w2,:3] = img2

    cv2.imwrite("Final_" + str(i) + ".jpg", visl)
```

But this just concatenates the image next to the other. As a result, I am unable to view it completely on the screen.

I checked on an online tool: https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/combine-two-images-into-one.php

This could automatically resize and place 2 images next to each other.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K47j4.jpg)

I was wondering how I could achieve this using the python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize the images using

```
dstimg = cv2.resize(srcimg,(x_,y_))
```

where x_ and y_ is the width and height of the destination image,*dstimg* that you want.

This way, you can resize both images to half of your screen resolution before concatenating them together